# Defining foreign key relationships for Rails' models seems not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this problem with respect to foreign keys
I want the foreign key in the table brains is called the_zombie_id
but when I go the console for to load data . the_zombie_id no exists

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :bio, :name

  has_one :brain, :foreign_key => 'the_zombie_id'
end

class Brain < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :flavor, :status, :zombie_id
  belongs_to :zombie
end
```

> 

```
  1.9.3-p547 :034 > brain=Brain.new  => #<Brain id: nil, zombie_id: nil, status: nil, flavor: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
> 1.9.3-p547 :035 > brain.the_zombie_id NoMethodError: undefined method `the_zombie_id' for #<Brain:0xaa0193c>
```

Comment: After your edit, I see that you have an zombie_id in your table (which respects the convention)... Why not just use it? Just remove the foreign_key definition in both models and use it normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Zombie model,

`has_one :brain`

You already have foreign_key `zombie_id` in the brains table.

In the Brain model, if you want to use `the_zombie_id` instead of `zombie_id`, then add the following code you can add to your Brain model.

```
alias_attribute :the_zombie_id, :zombie_id
```

Comment: friend. How use this name in the console? the_zombie_id

Comment: 1.9.3-p547 :033 > Brain.new
 => #<Brain id: nil, zombie_id: nil, status: nil, flavor: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> No show me that field called the_zombie_id

Comment: Thanks Bachan. It is necessary to define an alias? Because without an alias it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You want foreign_key not primary key

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :bio, :name

  has_one :brain, :foreign_key => 'the_zombie_id'
end
```

Also when you call for the brain you want `z.brain` if you have a `Zombie` assigned to `z`

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key must be always in the "belongs_to" part of the association. In this case your `Brain` model should have a `the_zombie_id` attribute.

Your models should look like following;

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :brain, :foreign_key => 'the_zombie_id'
end


class Brain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zombie, :foreign_key => 'the_zombie_id'
end
```

As your models are not following the naming conventions for the keys, you have to specify it in both models, but the attribute must be in the Brain model.

And please, note that adding the `foreign_key` option does not magically add the field into your database table. You have to create it through a migration.